# Highcharts Gauge Chart display value at tickPositions:

Tags: highcharts

Can someone please show me how to display dynamic value at the `[tickPositions:]` in a gauge chart?
I am parsing data from csv and value changes based on jquery filters. 
The example in this fiddle is very relevant but in my case value is dynamic.
http://jsfiddle.net/q5hgky25/3/

Answer (score 0):

For creating dynamic tick positions, instead of using

```
tickPositions:
```

You should use

```
tickPositioner: Function
```

Which is assigned a function that returns an array of numbers

Example:

```
yAxis: {
  tickPositoner: function() {
    return [8, 100] // or the dynamic values you want to assign
  }
}
```

Please refer to the documentation for more info: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.tickPositioner

Comment: Allu thanks for your reply. How can I pass value to return [8, 100]? Instead of 8 I want to pass value stored in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to [update yAxis](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.update) and set new tickPositions array.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3ud14udf/

```
  chart.series[0].setData([{y:42, color:'#f95d6f'}],false);
  var newTP = [0,42,100];
  chart.yAxis[0].update({tickPositions: newTP});
```